# Translate animation of Activity programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

This seems a simple task, but I don't find the solution.

I need to switch from **[Activity A]** to **[Activity B]** with a custom animation.
To do this I set the **[Activity B]** (in *onCreate*) with:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_out);
```

where *R.animator.slide_in* move in the **[Activity B]** with the code

```
<translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

and *R.animator.slide_out* is the inverse animation to move out the **[Activity A]**.

All it's ok, BUT **i wanna set programmatically the *android:fromYDelta*** of *R.animator.slide_in* cause it can change time to time.

What's the trick? Maybe I need to create the entire animation programmatically, but I really don't find the way…

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BUT i wanna set programmatically the android:fromYDelta of R.animator.slide_in cause it can change time to time.
```

There is not way of changing the animation of the xml programatically, also you can not use Objects within the `overridePendingTransition` method of the activity that it needs a resource from the xml to use as an animation.

**solution:**

Its either you will create multiple xml for each of the `YDelta` and that would require a lot of xml file or just stick to one xml file for all the animation.